# SwiftUI - ForEach - Type '_' has no member 'name'

Tags: foreach, swiftui

I'm am trying to `ForEach` over a String Array inside of a Class and receiving an error:
`Type '_' has no member 'name'`

I'm trying to model off what I read in this tutorial and don't understand why mine is failing to compile.
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/working-with-identifiable-items-in-swiftui

```
struct StatisticItem: Codable {
    let name: String
    let startValue: Int
    let modifier: Int
}

class Statistics: ObservableObject {
    let statisticsNames = ["One", "Two"]
    @Published var statList: [StatisticItem]

    init() {
        self.statList = [];
        for statisticsName in statisticsNames {
            self.statList.append(StatisticItem(name: statisticsName, startValue:  Int.random(in: 20 ... 100), modifier: 0))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var statistics = Statistics()

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            List {
                // Error shows up on this line: Type '_' has no member 'name'
                ForEach(statistics.statList, id:\.name) { stat in
                    TextField(stat.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is not because of `ForEach` but because of `TextField`, try to put a simple `Text` instead to see what happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your model needs to be modifiable (so used `var` instead of `let`)

```
struct StatisticItem: Codable {
    var name: String
    var startValue: Int
    var modifier: Int
}
```

Second, `TextField` requires `Binding`, so it should be like below

```
ForEach(Array(statistics.statList.enumerated()), id:\.1.name) { (i, stat) in
    TextField("", text: self.$statistics.statList[i].name)
}
```

Comment: Do you know why my code must be different than the tutorial?
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/working-with-identifiable-items-in-swiftui

The struct ExpenseItem in the tutorial uses `let`
The ForEach in the tutorial uses: `ForEach(expenses.items, id: \.name) { item in`

Comment: @JordanReed, they use read-only (or view-only, if you wish) demo with `Text`, but you intended to modify model, that's different thing.

Comment: HA!  Thanks!  I meant to use Text (not TextField).  So just changing that to Text solves my problem also.  And you other solution is good to know if I wish to change it.

Comment: Thanks @Asperi cleanest solution around, thank you so much, a real unblocker!